# getting error in class initialization list even-though matching datatype Const char* provided by converting string to c_str

Tags: c++

```
#ifndef BUFFEREDFILE_H
#define BUFFEREDFILE_H
#include<string>
#include<ios>
#include"FStream.h"
#include"GradingDeque.h"
class BufferedFile : private FStream {
public:
BufferedFile(const char* fname);
BufferedFile& get(char& c);
~BufferedFile();
std::ostream& put (char c);
bool eof() const;
void putback(char ch);
private:
std::istream& raw_get(char& c);
const char* filename;
std::streampos getpos;
std::streampos putpos;
GradingDeque<char> buffer;
bool hit_file_eof;
bool hit_empty_buffer;
};
#endif
```

StreamSource.h

```
   class StreamSource: public BufferedFile {
  public:
    //Functions needed:

    //ctor
    StreamSource(string srch, string file);

    //get
    StreamSource& get(char& c);

    //put
    ostream& put (char c);

    //eof
    bool eof();
    //found_partial_match
    // ...
    void found_partial_match(int i, char a);

      //will get character from either bf or from search string
    private:
        BufferedFile bf;
        string word;
        string fileName;
        bool readingFromFile;
    //store the search word
    //store the file name
    // ...
};
#endif
```

StreamSource.cpp

```
StreamSource::StreamSource(string srch, string file)
:bf(this->fileName.c_str()),word(srch),fileName(file),readingFromFile(false)
{
    // this->readingFromFile=false;
    // BufferedFile(this->fileName);
    // bf(file.c_str());this->fileName.c_str()
    // ;
}
```

I'm getting error: no matching function for call to ‘BufferedFile::BufferedFile() error. But, constructor type and passed arguments are const *str;

I have only defined only parameterized constructor for BufferedFile & i'm passing value while calling it inside the paramerized list of StreamSource constructor.

Comment: Why do you have `BufferedFile` as base class and as a member? You are initializing only the member, not the base class, in the shown constructor.

Comment: What is the exact errors you get? Please copy-paste the full and complete build-log into your question. Also, is it possible to minimize your [mre] even more (I believe it should be)? And please add comments on the lines where you get the errors.

Comment: Also, your `StreamSource::get` function returns a `StreamSource` reference. Why doesn't the `StreamSource::put` function do the same? What `ostream` reference is it returning?

Comment: @user17732522 Hi, Can you tell me what changes I need to do? What you are telling might solve the problem

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's my school assignment. My instructor is not available now. So, I'm asking on stackoverflow.

Comment: @AkshayBarpute Decide whether you to inherit from `BufferedFile` or whether you want a `BufferedFile` as `bf` data member. Then use only one of the two.

Comment: It's initializing the base class of `StreamSource` that's the problem here. You'd need to do `StreamSource::StreamSource(string srch, string file) : BufferFile(...), bf...`. Furthermore there's an issue with the initialization order: member variables are initialized in the order in which they are declared, i.e. `bf` is initialized **before** `fileName` resulting in access to the pointer passed in undefined behaviour. Note that the base class is initialized before, so you'd run into the same issue there unless you modify `BufferFile` and have it own the string data.

Comment: @ AnoopRana Marking this question as dupe the currently linked one is incorrect, since the linked question deals with issues of initializing member variables, not with initializing the base class. I'm pretty sure there's a suitable dupe out there, but this isn't the correct one.

Comment: @user17732522 I can't make changes in BufferedFile. bf is data member of StreamSource. Can you tell me what I need to change in constructor initialization list.

Comment: Remember that inheritance is an "is a" relationship. Is `StreamBuffer` really an `BufferedFile`? Or should you use composition and only contain a `BufferedFile`? Using both composition and inheritance seems wrong. My recommendation is composition, and you remove the inheritance.

Comment: @AkshayBarpute I am not talking about changing `BufferedFile`. I am talking about changing `StreamSource`. If `StreamSource` is supposed to have a `BufferedFile` data member named `bf`, then why do you also inherit `StreamSource` from `BufferedFile`, i.e. why do you have `: public BufferedFile` in `class StreamSource: public BufferedFile {`? If you want `StreamSource` to have a `BufferedFile` member instead of inheriting from it, then remove that part and the error will go away.